Magento 2.4.7-p3 Deprecate class Action\Action and constructor parent::__construct($context);
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Module\Coord\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}


Deprecate the use of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action and Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context, you can replace them with Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface (for GET actions) or Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface (for POST actions). This approach avoids inheriting the Action class and its constructor by defining the controller class as an implementation of HttpGetActionInterface or HttpPostActionInterface.
Updated Code

Implement HttpGetActionInterface instead of extending Action.
Remove the parent::__construct call.

Explanation

HttpGetActionInterface: Implements the appropriate interface rather
than extending Action.

Removal of Context and parent::__construct call: The Context
parameter is no longer needed, simplifying the constructor.


Code:
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2024
 * All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 * Check module
 * Magento 2.4.7-p3
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Module\Coord\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

/**
 * Class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
 *
 * @class Index
 * @since 11/13/2024
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        protected PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ){
    }

    /**
     * Function execute view action
     *
     * @return ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute(): ResultInterface
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}

